# Watching guide for DS9

Tags: star-trek, suggested-order, star-trek-deep-space-nine

This may be somewhat too subjective a question, but I'll try anyways.

I'm not a trekkie, but I do like me some *Star Trek*. I'm most familiar with *TNG* and *Voyager*.

I want to like *DS9*, and there are aspects of it that I do, but there is a lot of it that I find off-putting, and I believe it is regarded as the least liked, though I could be wrong.

Does anyone know of a watching guide for *DS9* that points out specific episodes to watch that further the story arcs while skipping episodes that are more... fluff.

Again, very subjective; hopefully what I'm getting at will come through.

Comment: DS9 is different that in it later season it has an overarching plot that is involved with most episodes.  This makes it harder to skip episodes in the later seasons and what do you consider fluff?  DS9 does a good job bring back minor thing in later episodes.

Comment: This is the first I've heard of DS9 being "least liked."  (Although perhaps attitudes have changed over time.)  Usually Voyager (or Enterprise) is the punching bag of the Star Trek shows.

Comment: I was never much of a fan of DS9 either. I watched the show from pilot to finale, but it just didn't have that "grab" for me like TNG did. Even Voyager isn't as great as TNG was. I don't know what it is about TNG that the other series/movies just can't make up for. The TNG crew is(was) awesome! The actors were great, the Enterprise D was a slick ship (E is cool too, despite being subjected to movie-only appearance). Is it based on writers?

Comment: @Steve-O I can get behind people disliking Enterprise, even though I think it's fine. But I know a guy who much prefers DS9 to Voyager, and I think he's got a screw loose. He actually *likes* the Ferengi.

Comment: @Styxsksu I was speaking more of the early seasons. I want to watch DS9 so that I CAN understand the Dominion war

Comment: I know what i'm about to say may cause a riot but... The Early seasons of DS9 are somewhat bland, similar to the first season of TNG, however TNG found its footing very quickly and continued to improve, DS9 took a bit longer to get there but did so, and the last couple of seasons with the dominion war and some of the best Star Trek IMO... this is JUST my opinion, don't hate me for saying it... oh while i'm throwing my 2 cents in, Voyager was the worst of the lot...

Comment: @BladeWraith I know people dislike Voyager (for some reason), but it's definitely better than Enterprise.

Comment: @JohnDoe, yes Enterprise had its fault, but they at least tried to do something different in a way that at least fit slightly within the universe... less said about discovery the better obviously. Voyager was not really any different from TNG different apart from they fixed all the issues they encountered by themselves without help from the federation basically making it the Starship Mary Sue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't provide much more than a lmgtfy answer, but I've been following a mix of the following two watchlists [DS9 in 82.5 hours](https://medium.com/maxistentialism-blog/star-trek-deep-space-nine-in-82-5-hours-10acde591fd2) and [DS9 Condensed](https://www.geek.com/geek-cetera/star-trek-deep-space-nine-condensed-how-to-watch-the-most-story-driven-trek-1613741/). They list the episodes in the weaker first two seasons that you need to understand the later plot. I got hooked around the start of season 3 and am now only skipping the really bad fluff episodes.